# Unable to validate user login via code igniter

Tags: php, validation, codeigniter

I've been rebuilding my site with code igniter and am having trouble validating the users info. To put it simply, I can type in gibberish to my login form and it will take me to the 'welcome' page no matter what.

Click [HERE](https://gist.github.com/0647c46d3bdf78c1f037) to view my code

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the session data being created? You should add `$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);` to your constructor and then you can inspect the db queries and the session data.  -- It would also be helpful to see the `home/dashboard` code and view

Comment: Also, I'm not judging, but it looks like you're storing plain-text passwords in your database. You should encrypt those.

Comment: I'm going to use SHA1 with salt, I'm just trying to get the sign in working properly first then I will modify

Comment: Ah, sorry about bringing that up then. Just my paranoid nature.

Comment: no,I appreciate the looking out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if you have more than one problem, but this is definitely one of them:

```
if($query->num_rows = 1) {
```

That should be:

```
if($query->num_rows() == 1) {
```

Comment: Check out this page from the CI User Guide.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html

Answer (score 0):

What does `$this->login();` do in the model?

Anyways, this seems to work correctly for me:

Model:

```
public function validate($email, $password) {
    if ($email == 0 || $password == 0) return false;

    //SEE IF THEIR INFO IS IN THE DB
    $this->db->where('email', $email);
    $this->db->where('password', $password);
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    return ($query->num_rows() == 1);
}
```

Controller:

```
public function validate() {
    //THIS LOADS THE MODEL THAT TAKES ALL THEIR INFO THEY TYPED AND INSERT IN THE DB
    $this->load->model('auth_model');
    $this->load->library('session');    

    $query = $this->auth_model->validate($this->input->post('email'),$this->input->post('password'));

    if($query) {
        // IF THEIR INFO MATCHES UP, THEN START A SESSION WITH CI'S BUILT IN SESSION CLASS 
        $data = array(
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'password' => $this->input->post('password'),
            'is_logged_in' => true
            );
            // AUTO LOADED SESSION CLASS 
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);

            //THIS WILL TAKE THEM TO THE DASHBOARD PAGE IF EVERYTHING CHECKS OUT 
            redirect('home/dashboard');
    } else {
        // IF INCORRECT THEN RELOAD THE FORM FOR NOW
        $this->index();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Minboost's answer is definitely something you should fix before proceeding, but the assignment should evaluate to true, and you'd have the opposite problem.  People would login no matter what.

Are you storing sessions in the database or with cookies?  I've had problems before with setting cookies and then immediately redirecting.  Some browsers seem to have issues with the order of the Set-Cookie vs. Location headers.  You might try to rule that out before banging your head too hard.

Other possibilities include A) code you're not showing us that might be redirecting back to the login page for some reason, B) routing issues, C) something else you could figure out by tracing the response headers in FireBug.